# Need help for installing 'dlib' library

Tags: opencv, cmd, dlib

I've been trying to install dlib library for a while now and have tried almost all the solutions available on the web.
While installing this file I'm facing an error:

> ERROR: dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Help me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cmake first as it is required for Dlib, get installation files from [here](https://cmake.org/download/) or use `pip install cmake`.

Then install Anaconda 3.

Then run, `pip install dlib` to install dlib making sure that you're using python2, instead of python3.